# How am I granted access to a protected Windows share without entering a password?

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2012-r2, file-sharing

I was logged in to a local administrator account on a Windows 2012 R2 server yesterday and noticed I was granted immediate (passwordless) access to the C$ admin share on another 2012 R2 server.  These machines are joined to different domains with one-way trust in the opposite direction, so at first I was thrown off and fairly concerned, but after further investigation I believe I was just experiencing the behavior described [here](https://serverfault.com/a/400150/110282).

Although the question I've linked to is marked "answered", I'd like more information about how and why this works than "permissions will generally flow".  I've searched the internet extensively, but I don't know what the behavior is called so it's difficult to find any information.

Does anyone have information on the details of how, when and why this happens (Microsoft documentation of the behavior would be preferred)?  I don't recall this being the behavior in previous versions of Windows, either, so knowing if/when it was introduced would be helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See the accepted answer for this question and the linked article in the answer - http://serverfault.com/questions/454520/how-exactly-does-silent-authentication-using-matching-local-accounts-on-a-wind

Comment: Was the password the same?

Comment: `I don't recall this being the behavior in previous versions of Windows` - afaik, automatically authenticating to machines when you have the same username/password has been happening since at least NT 3.5. So, basically always.

Comment: I also don't remember this **not** always being the default behavior.

Comment: @joeqwerty - great answer, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Zoredache, joeqwerty - you guys are probably right, I've maybe just never noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @joeqwerty above, this is called passthrough NTLM authentication, and is referenced in a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/454520/how-exactly-does-silent-authentication-using-matching-local-accounts-on-a-wind).